# NGINX Rewrite URL to pass it to upstream server

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have an application on an EC2 instance behind NGINX. NGINX serves the client as follows

```
https://localhost:443/org/consumer/consumer-app
```

My app in the backend only understands

```
http://localhost:8080/consumer/consumer-app
```

Both NGINX and app are on the same EC2 instance. I want a way to eliminate the /org/ before I pass the request to the upstream server. I tried **rewrite** directive but couldn't get it to work. What's the best way to do it?

Also, I want the /org/ reintroduced back by NGINX when responding back to the client.

Any help offered would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is it only on /org/consumer/consumer-app or it is on /org/* ?

Comment: just /org/. I figured the solution without using rewrite.